# Call a function when counter reaches some value without if statement

Tags: c, if-statement, embedded

Lets say I have a function named `loop()`. In this `loop()` I increment a counter `count`.
I have few functions, `A()`, `B()`, `C()`, etc.

I want to call each one of these functions when the counter reaches some value (different for every function).
My current code looks like:

```
static unsigned int count = 0;
void loop(){
    if (count == VALUE_ONE)
        A();
    if (count == VALUE_TWO)
        B();
    if (count == VALUE_THREE)
        C();
    ..... //more cases

    if (count == MAX_VAL)
        count = 0;
    else
        count++;
}
```

`VALUE_*` are `#define`s so they are not being changed during the program.

Right now I am using regular `if` statements to check the counter value. But I want to avoid using the `if` statement to avoid branch mispredictions.

Is there a better way to do this? Something that will actually avoid branch mispredictions etc?

### Edit:

The goal here is to optimize this part of code in order to make it in faster, as for now it sometimes doesn't finish until the time it should.  I am aware that there might be a problem with function `A()`, `B()`, etc, but for now I am asking about this specific case.

To make it clear, `VALUE_ONE`, `VALUE_TWO`, `VALUE_THREE`, etc might be very large values and not increasing by `1`. For example it might be:

```
#define VALUE_ONE 20
#define VALUE_TWO 1500
#define VALUE_THREE 99777
```

My compiler version is: gcc (GCC) 4.4.7

Comment: As it stands, your code is going to evaluate each 'if' statement when at most only one of them will fire. You should use 'else if' at least. In the end, you are going to need some conditional logic. The best thing that you can do is unroll the function calls and let the compiler optimiser do its work.

Comment: What am I thinking about? You could use a jump table -- store the addresses of the called functions in an array (but you'll still need to do a range check). Someone else will have to show you how. My C is a little rusty.

Comment: Use a [state machine](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/95569/best-practice-to-keep-main-in-embedded-systems/96415#96415) based on function pointers.

Comment: Why not you use a switch statement?

Comment: The question is: Why you want such an behaviour? Do you want to optimize something or do you try to get exact timeing with your loop? Then the `if/branch mispredictions` is your least problem. Please add more informations what your real goal is.

Comment: What's wrong with this if-else structure?

Comment: Sidenote: incrementing a signed integer beyond its maximum value (`INT_MAX` here) invokes undefined behaviour. If your counter is supposed to wrap-around, use an unsigned integer (which is guaranteed to wrap). If you need a guaranteed bit-width, use a fixed-width or least-width type (the latter are guaranteed to exist, the latter have to on 8bit/byte platforms). See `stdint.h`.

Comment: @jeb yes, I want to optimize. The `loop()` function is called by some kind of interrupt once every few ms. There are more than 3 functions/cases so I thought if there is a simple way to optimize this it might help.

Comment: When the `loop()` is called every few ms, then it's absolutely nonsense to optimize it for a part of a micro second

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why in the world are you worried about branch misprediction?  Do you have a working program?  Does it run too slowly?  Have you narrowed the problem to branch misprediction in the code you present?  Unless the answer to each of those questions is "yes", you are engaging in premature optimization.

Moreover, the conditional branches in the code you present appear to be highly predictable, at least if the counter is expected routinely to reach values in the tens or hundreds of thousands or more, as the updated example code seems to indicate.  A misprediction rate on the order of 0.00001 or less -- which is about what you could expect -- will not have a measurable performance impact.  Indeed, handling code such as you've presented is the bread and butter of branch prediction.  You could hardly ask for a case more friendly to a branch-prediction unit.

In any event, since you are concerned about branch misprediction, your question must be not so much about avoiding the `if` statements in particular, but about avoiding conditional logic in general.  As such, a `switch` construct probably is not better, at least not for the situation you describe, wherein you want to call functions only for a handful of the large number of distinct values the function will see, sprinkled across a wide range.  Although the compiler could, in principle, implement such a `switch` via a jump table, it is unlikely to do so in your case because of how large the needed table would be, and how few of the elements would differ from the one for the default case.

A hash table has also been discussed, but that's no better, because then either you need conditional logic to distinguish between cache hits and cache misses, or else your hash table must for every input provide a function (pointer) to be called.  Calling a function on every iteration would be far more costly than what you are doing now.

Additionally, you need a perfect hash function to avoid conditional logic in the HT implementation.  If the possible values of your counter are bounded by a small enough number that a hash table / perfect hash could be used to avoid conditional logic, then a plain array of function pointers would be lighter-weight than a hash table, and could serve the same purpose.  It would still have the same problem with function-call overhead, however.  If you insist on avoiding conditional logic then this would probably be the best way to go for your particular problem.  But don't.

Comment: Thanks, your answer really _solve_ the problem. Don't try to optimize before you have a problem.

Comment: Well, I guess that your answer sums it all up. I might have jumped too fast to a conclusion that this might be the problem and I thought why not to try fixing this if its simple. But as I see it is probably really not the problem in my actual code. Anyway, I absolutely learned something new today. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: @A.Sarid: To be fair: if that is in an interrupt handler which is called every few seconds, there indeed could be a problem, if other interrupts are blocked during execution. But that goes too far for stack overflow.

Comment: @Olaf, although it's not out of the question that there would be a performance bottleneck in that function, it does seem unlikely that such a bottleneck would arise from branch misprediction.  I see no reason to think that any kind of reorganization to avoid conditional code in this case would improve performance.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Read my answer, I wrote much the same. (wonder what I did wrong not to be the accepted answer - no grudge, just curious). But is indeed have timing issues in interrupt handlers, although they are themselves not critical, but would block other interrupts too long. Debugging such issues can be really a bitch, so sometimes it _is_ a good idea to keep that in mind from the beginning. That's all what I say.

Answer (score 4):

Leave optimisations to the compiler in the first place. Concentrate on writing human-readable code. Optimise only iff you have a timing problem and after you profiled the code. Then concentrate on the hot-spots. If some code is good for branch-prediction is hard to predict with modern CPUs.

Use a [`switch`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.4.2) (for an easier to read introduction please check a good C book) statement to make the code better readable:

```
switch ( count ) {
    case VALUE_ONE:
        f1();
        break;

    case VALUE_TWO:
        f2();
        break;

    ...

    default:
        // be aware to catch illegal/forgotten values, unless you
        // are absolutely sure they can be ignored safely.
        // still having a default label is good style to signal "I
        // though about it".
        break;
}
```

That is not only the most readable version, but also gives the compiler the best chance to optimize the code.

If the values are just increasing by 1 (`1`, `2`, `3`, ...), modern compilers will automatically generate a jump-table, even for partial successions (`1`, `2`, `3`, `7`, `8`, etc.), so that is as fast as a manually created function-table. If they are not, it still often will generate something like `if ... else if ... else if ...` constructs.

Note the case-labels must be *constant-expressions*.

**Edit:** After you clarified the values may not be adcascent, my answer still holds true. Depending on the number of compare-values, the `switch` still is the best solution unless **prooved** wrong. Try this first, profile and only optimise iff necessary. A hash-table might not be worth the effort.

Even if you'd use a hash-function, the `switch` above will come in handy. Just use the hash-value instead of `count`.

Comment: @Olaf Thanks. So let me see if I get this, if my values are as I wrote in my edit, will my compiler still make a jump-table? Does it worth maybe to implement what Lundin suggested in the [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39575640/call-a-function-when-counter-reaches-some-value-without-if-statement/39575787#comment66461895_39575640)?

Comment: Traditionally, switch statements tend to optimize poorly on various embedded systems compilers. So function-pointer based jump tables are traditionally faster, and more commonly used for the implementation of state machines. Some modern compilers might optimize the switch into a jump table if you are lucky. Disassemble and see what code you end up with.

Comment: @Lundin: That's why I was very clear first to implement to simplest version (i.e. `switch`) and profile **iff** there really is a problem. Profiling can be the framework-supporte automatic profiling, but as well inspecting the machine code generated. Anyway, for the values shown by the edit, a simple function-table indexed by value also fails and especially on smaller embedded MCUs a good hash-function easily may take more time than the `switch`. Without more information from OP, it is not possible to recommend an OTS solution.

Comment: @Lundin: Re poor optimisation: Might be, but such compiler should be kicked out of development asap. I've seen embedded compilers optimise `switch` to a table more than 20 years ago (was pretty surprised they did). Nowadays we can definitively expect such simple optimisations. Still it most likely will not for the values shown. I doubt a compiler generates a hash table automatically, though. Yet an appealing thought (you know about any compiler being that smart?).

Comment: @KlasLindbäck: I added the `perror` just to show that one always should treat this case. Note that some coding standard do require a `default`. But you are right, here it should just do nothing. I'll edit that.

Comment: @A.Sarid: As I wrote, a jump-table is nonsense for such widely spread values. And no, I'm confident it will not. I don't understand why you care in the first place. If you have well founded reason to worry **that** is your hotspot, add all relevant information to your question. For those three values given, I'd not even think about any other solution until then.

Comment: @A.Sarid: Just that: gcc will use a table if the trade-of between the table and discrete compares is acceptable. But before caring about this, I'd use a more recent version, 4.4 is pretty old now and - depending on your architecture - gcc made great advances, which well possibly make your code faster without hand-crafting the above.

Comment: @Olaf Thanks for your effort and all the information you gave here. Regarding GCC, I will absolutely upgrade the version and see if it will make any difference for me. Anyway, regarding accepting your answer or Johns, I guess there is no 100% correct answer here, there are many parameters and cases I need to take into account. All answers given are good and informative. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm skeptical whether the original function is a bottleneck or an effective place to be optimizing.  But hey, I like puzzles...

Given that the count is incrementing and the match values are increasing, you really only need to test against the upcoming match value.  And while you can't use your match values as an array index you could create states that can be used as an array index.  Try something like this.

```
static unsigned int count = 0;

typedef enum 
{
    WAITING_FOR_VALUE_ONE = 0,
    WAITING_FOR_VALUE_TWO,
    WAITING_FOR_VALUE_THREE,
    ...,
    WAITING_FOR_MAX_VALUE,
    MAX_STATES
} MyStates;

static MyStates state = WAITING_FOR_VALUE_ONE;

void waitForValueOne()
{
    if (count == VALUE_ONE)
    {
        A();
        state++;
    }
}

void waitForValueTwo()
{
    if (count == VALUE_TWO)
    {
        B();
        state++;
    }
}

void waitForMaxValue()
{
    if (count == MAX_VAL)
    {
        count = 0;
        state = 0;
    }
}

void (*stateHandlers[MAX_STATES]) () =
{
    waitForValueOne,
    waitForValueTwo,
    waitForValueThree,
    ...
    waitForMaxValue
}

void loop()
{
    (*stateHandlers[state])();
    count++;
}
```

After count reaches MAX_VAL, your original implementation will run the next loop with count = 0 whereas my implementation will run the next loop with count = 1.  But I'm sure you can fix that if it's important.

**Update:**
I don't like how `loop` called the state handler every count.  It really only needs to call the state handler when there is a match.  And also the comparison doesn't need to be repeated in every state handler function if it's performed in `loop`.  Here are a few edits that implement this improvement.

```
static MyStates state = WAITING_FOR_VALUE_ONE;
static unsigned int matchValue = VALUE_ONE;

void waitForValueOne()
{
    A();
    state++;
    matchValue = VALUE_TWO;
}

void waitForValueTwo()
{
    B();
    state++;
    matchValue = VALUE_THREE;
}

void waitForMaxValue()
{
    count = 0;
    state = 0;
    matchValue = VALUE_ONE;
}

void loop()
{
    if (count == matchValue)
    {
        (*stateHandlers[state])();
    }
    count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case I can't see any reason for an optimiziation.
But in the case your interrupt will be fired every 20µs and your handler consumes 50% of the complete cpu time, as you check aginst 200 values, then and only then you could change your code.

For an incrementing counter, you only need a single `if` as you always know which value will be the next one.

```
void isr(void)
{
  count++;
  if (count == nextValue)
  {
    if ( count == VALUE_ONE )
    {
       A();
       nextValue=VALUE_TWO;
    }
    else if ( count == VALUE_TWO )
    {
       B();
       nextValue=VALUE_THREE;
    }
     ...

  }
}
```

In 99% of the time, the ISR() only needs to increment the counter and check that the value isn't reached.

In reallity, I would use an array of actions and times, instead of the `if else if` block.

Comment: In your code, after calling A() and B(), I believe you intended to set `nextValue` rather than `count`.